# Monotouch crashes with no exceptions

Tags: exception, crash, xamarin.ios

I built a monotouch app it randomly crashes after user fnishes signup the problem is that no exception is being thrown, I tried to catch that with the debugger while testing it on a device  (of course I set it up to catch all exceptions) I even tried to set up crash tool such as HockeyApp but those crashes don't appear any where.

How can I solve this? help please!

Comment: You can get more information in the device's console (you can view it from Xamarin Studio -> View -> Pads -> iOS Device Log), and crash reports will appear in Xcode's Organizer (assuming you're not using any other crash reporting tools).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Raygun.io](https://raygun.io/). It will log any unhandled exceptions to the dashboard. Add it via a nuget package and then you can set it up with one line in your Main.cs:

```cs
namespace Myapp.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mindscape.Raygun4Net.RaygunClient.Attach("enter your api key here");

            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```